# Refer an element to the DOM with h:link

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, href

My question is simply, it's possible make a href to a element of the DOM?

Something like this:

```
  <h:link outcome="page#form" value="Edit"></h:link>
```

That's would print something like this:

```
   <a href="/page#form.jsf">Edit</a>
```

Obviously, I tried this and didn't work, It can be done in JSF? And if can... which tag I must use?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `fragment` attribute of [`<h:link>`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) to bring the identifier of the requested page into focus:

```
<h:link value="Edit" outcome="/page" fragment="form" />
```

Though using plain HTML elements, like `a`, or `span`, or any other, is perfectly valid as well.

Of course, you *could* also use `<h:outputLink>` for that purpose.